# How to specify proxy for veeam backup job?

Tags: veeam

I have one server veeam 8 backup & replication and some hosts with virtual machines. Also I installed veeam proxies (one proxy for each host) and added its into the veeam main server. How should i specify, which veeam proxy backup each job must use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify proxies on the "storage" page of the backup job configuration wizard. By default, "automatic selection" mode is used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manually select which proxy servers to use, but I would suggest sticking to automatic selection. This will be beneficial when one proxy goes down for some reason. Thanks!